# How to check keyboard language in terminal mac os

Tags: swift, macos, terminal

I'm a developer of software that draws the user's typing(Keylogger) for macOS user's in Swift-Xcode, but I have a problem with some of the languages ​​of the keyboard, I want to check what is the language of the keyboard at the moment, I want to run a command in the terminal (if possible, or you have a better way) and see what is the language of the keyboard at the moment. In order to create better software that can decipher any language, not just English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages
```

on the terminal, you will get a list of languages that the user can pick from.

---

Edit:

Sorry I didn't realize my approach was correct only because I am using the same language as my top preference one.

If you want to determine the input sources, you can instead do:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
```

So for example,

`defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist AppleSelectedInputSources | egrep -w 'KeyboardLayout Name'`

shows you the name of the selected keyboard layout.

---

Note that if the above command returns empty, it might mean that the selected keyboard layout does not have a name, so you might need to check the Input Mode instead or just ignore it (e.g. Hand-Writing, Chinese Pinyin, ...).

Comment: Thank for your help, it is work and shows me all the options of the language the i have, but not the current language that im using now.

Comment: Sorry I should have tested it by switching to other languages, correction made.